# Integrating Twitter Oauth AND Facebook Connect for login on a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, oauth, ruby-on-rails-plugins, twitter

I'm developing a rails app where the user needs to be able to create an account & login with either facebook OR twitter.

It seems pretty straightforward if I want to do one or the other, but implementing both looks like it could present some difficulty.

Does anybody else have any experience with implementing both Twitter's oauth and Facebook connect in a single app?

Thanks in advance,
Casey

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) library to add authentication, then add in Facebook and Twitter support using the "add ons" (see [Facebook](http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect) and [Twitter](http://github.com/jrallison/authlogic_oauth)).